# Boundaries of graphical objects not displayed correctly

Tags: bugs, image, legending

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

I have encountered two situations where *Mathematica* 10 is mishandling the outer pixels of plainly simple objects.

I input this:

```
Rasterize[Graphics[{}, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> {19, 19}]]
```

It should basically create a 19x19 pixel black square, but instead I get this:

[image: Extra white image]

If you select the image you will see an extra white pixel row on the top. Indeed, this is because the `ImageDimensions[%]` gives `{19, 20}`. A similar problem occurs with some other pixel sizes.

---

A similar effect takes place in barlegends:

```
GraphicsRow[{BarLegend[{"DeepSeaColors", {0, 1}}], BarLegend[{"DeepSeaColors", {0, 1}}, 
  LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"]}]
```

These are two bar legends going from 0 to 1, but the second one is reversed. The images look like this:

[image]

Here, the regular bar legend is okay, but the reversed one misses a thin grey line on one side.

**Questions**: Is it a bug? Does is happen only on my machine (Ubuntu 14)? Is it fixable (especially for the Legends)?

Comment: I got `{19, 19}` in MMA 10.

Comment: @seismatica, which is interesting, thank you!

Comment: I can not reproduce what you report with V10 running on OS X.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Does it include plot legends?

Comment: No. The bar legends look as you show them.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I see. Also, in Mathematica 9 both bar legends look ok on my machine, but not in version 10.

Comment: For the first example with `Rasterize` I get {19, 19} in MMa 10.0.0 under Win7 x64. Which version are you using?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 and Mathematica 10.0, all together with NVIDIA Quadro 2000 card.

Comment: This works for me on V10.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to isolate the problem with `BarLegend` in v.10.0.0. Yes, it is clearly a bug.

Let us see the how the thin grey lines are implemented:

```
Cases[
 ToBoxes[BarLegend[{"DeepSeaColors", {0, 1}}, 
   LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"]], _LineBox, Infinity]
```

> ```
> {LineBox[
>   NCache[{{-(15/2), 225/2}, {15/2, 225/2}, {15/
>      2, -(225/2)}, {-(15/2), -(225/2)}}, {{-7.5, 112.5}, {7.5, 
>      112.5}, {7.5, -112.5}, {-7.5, -112.5}}]], 
>  LineBox[{{7.5, 112.5}, {7.5, -112.5}}], 
>  LineBox[{{{7.5, 112.5}, Offset[{4., 0}, {7.5, 112.5}]}, {{7.5, 67.5},
>      Offset[{4., 0}, {7.5, 67.5}]}, {{7.5, 22.5}, 
>     Offset[{4., 0}, {7.5, 22.5}]}, {{7.5, -22.5}, 
>     Offset[{4., 0}, {7.5, -22.5}]}, {{7.5, -67.5}, 
>     Offset[{4., 0}, {7.5, -67.5}]}, {{7.5, -112.5}, 
>     Offset[{4., 0}, {7.5, -112.5}]}}], 
>  LineBox[{{{7.5, 101.25}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, 101.25}]}, {{7.5, 90.}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, 90.}]}, {{7.5, 78.75}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, 78.75}]}, {{7.5, 56.25}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, 56.25}]}, {{7.5, 45.}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, 45.}]}, {{7.5, 33.75}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, 33.75}]}, {{7.5, 11.25}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, 11.25}]}, {{7.5, 0.}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, 0.}]}, {{7.5, -11.25}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, -11.25}]}, {{7.5, -33.75}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, -33.75}]}, {{7.5, -45.}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, -45.}]}, {{7.5, -56.25}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, -56.25}]}, {{7.5, -78.75}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, -78.75}]}, {{7.5, -90.}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, -90.}]}, {{7.5, -101.25}, 
>     Offset[{2.5, 0.}, {7.5, -101.25}]}}]}
> ```

Let us visualize them:

```
Graphics[%]
```

> [image: graph]

We see that the left line is simply absent. Why? Because the second line `LineBox[{{7.5, 112.5}, {7.5, -112.5}}]` should have negative X coordinates in order to be placed on the left:

```
Graphics[{Line[NCache[{{-(15/2), 225/2}, {15/2, 225/2}, {15/2, -(225/2)}, {-(15/2), -(225/2)}}, {{-7.5, 112.5}, {7.5, 112.5}, {7.5, -112.5}, {-7.5, -112.5}}]], 
Line[{{-7.5, 112.5}, {-7.5, -112.5}}]}]
```

[image: gr]

So the source of the problem is now clear: the developer just forgot to change the sign of the coordinates of this line when implemented `LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"` on the basis of already implemented `LegendLayout -> "Column"`.

Comment: Greatly many thanks for clear analysis! I suppose, it also proves that the issue with legends is independent from the one with the boundary pixels. I will report is to Wolfram support therefore.

Comment: Yes, it certainly proves that these are completely independent issues.

Comment: It was actually the legend issue which concerned me the most, so I mark your answer accepted. If there is more input from Wolfram support, I will add it into the question section. Thanks again!