# Rastersize: Problems with small images (image size, antialiasing)

Tags: rasterize

I wrote:

```
RasterizeWord[word_, font_, size_] := 
Rasterize[Style[word, FontFamily -> font, Black],RasterSize -> size,Background -> Gray] 
f=RasterizeWord["A", "Arial", 20]
```

and I got (after zoom):

[image]

with 18 pixels (easy to calculate). Why??

How to make it the grayscale?

I set antialising to none in Unity Tweak Tool (Linux) and I got:

[image]

So I tried:

```
RasterSize -> size, ImageSize -> size
```

I got the same result.
But it is interesting that in GIMP:

[image]

when I `Export["f.png", f]`. I think something is wrong with the zoom.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You could disable [subpixel antialiasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) in your OS's text rendering settings.

Comment: Replace RasterSize by ImageSize, you will get the correct width, see also recent http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64758/rasterize-resolution-option-not-working-properly

Comment: Thanks Alexey, but it is not true.

Comment: @ZYX, on my system (MMA 10, Ubuntu 14), your code < Rasterize["A", RasterSize -> 20] // ImageDimensions > gives {9,18} . If you call instead < Rasterize["A", ImageSize -> 20] // ImageDimensions > , you get {20,34} on my configuration. Please, let me know, if you get a different result.

Comment: Though, actually, I had a very similar problem with resolution here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57688/boundaries-of-graphical-objects-not-displayed-correctly . The behavior there described has been confirmed as a bug. @Szabolcs: May that be a duplicate?

Comment: I have the same results.